# jsp/tomcat url rewrite

Tags: jsp, url-rewriting, tomcat6

I have a url like this ; **www.example.com/hotel/hotel_name**

I want to rewrite url like ; **www.example.com/hotel_name**

i tried step by step like www.tuckey.org says. But it not works.

in my **urlrewrite.xml**

```
    <rule>
        <from>^/hotel/([a-zA-Z_]+)$</from>
        <to>/hotel?url=$1</to>
    </rule>
```

when I delete *"hotel"* form rule, site going down.

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Did I missed something? Thanks for your help

Comment: we solved problem; 

    <rule>
        <from>^/([a-zA-Z_]+)**_**$</from>
        <to>/hotel?url=$1</to>
    </rule>

that was problem